# WPF RibbonWindow tab bar style

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I would like to create a RibbonWindow Application using WPF and where tab bar has the same look & feel that the Window title bar. Like Office 2010 does:

[image]

In my application, the tab bar has a colour blue-gray which is the default when adding Ribbon control:

[image]

May I ask you your help on how to have this same layout please?

Comment: The unfortunate answer is that unless you are willing to restyle the entire Ribbon using Blend you will likely never get it to match the Office style. Microsoft has admitted they do not plan on improving the Ribbon beyond a second class citizen in the framework. Your best bet is to buy a Ribbon from a company or to switch to something like Fluent (buggy).

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that are not possible with the WPF ribbon that office does. However, most functionality can be used when using a `RibbonWindow` instead of the normal WPF `Window` class.

I assume, the functionality you are looking for is called QuickAccessToolbar.

Comment: The OP was fairly specific that he was looking for the same colors and styles. To which the answer is "Not without a lot of work."